# Rails 4 route issue when I try to navigate back via links in nav bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm newer to Rails and having an issue with my routes on a simple blog. I have the following routes below. When I navigate to example.com/posts then click on a post, everything seems to work fine. If I click on the Post link in my navbar to go back to example.com/post I end up with example.com/posts/posts. I've tried several different things from the Rails guide and just can't seem to figure this out. Thank you in advance for the assistance.

```
TestBed::Application.routes.draw do

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
root "pages#home"

get "/home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"

end
```

**Edited to add navbar details**

```
<li><%= link_to "Blog", "posts" %></li>
```

Comment: Can you show the navbar code?

Comment: @vee I added the code in my navbar

Comment: Try: `<%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %>`.  This will take you to `/posts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `link_to` helper you have `"posts"` as the URL.  This appends the string `posts` to the end of the current url, which is the reason why you're seeing `example.com/posts/posts`.

To have the link properly point to `/posts`, modify your `link_to` call as follows:

```
<li><%= link_to "Blog", "/posts" %></li>
```

or use route helper:

```
<li><%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %></li>
```

Comment: This solved the problem and I appreciate the added context regarding how my current setup was just appending a string. I wasn't picking up on that so that was helpful. I tried your solution earlier but forgot to remove the parentheses around the post_path thus I need to be more attentive to these details.